# What is the under the hood reason that we can use nested for loops in list comprehensions

Tags: python, loops, nested, list-comprehension

I've been studying list comprehensions and something stopped me for days.

A simple list comprehension has the form

`[expression for item in iterable]`

the equivalent `for` loop is

```
li=[]
for item in iterable
    li.append(item)
```

If I'm right what generally a list comprehension does is it iterates through the iterable, evaluates the expression for each iteration, then appends it to the list.

Whatever should happen inside the `for` loop is written at the beginning of the liscomp.

We can think that in a listcomp Python only allows one expression and `for` loop's suit is permitted to have only an `if` clause or nested `for` loops.

To quote a book I was reading it states that

> *Since list comprehensions produce lists, that is, iterables, and since the syntax for list comprehensions requires an iterable, it is possible to nest list comprehensions. This is the equivalent of having nested `for … in` loops.*

This confused my understanding.

Does this says the reason for having a listcomp like `[s+z for s in iterable_1 for z in iterable_2]`

Can someone please explain what this says.

Comment: a) it does not automatically do a list append, it simply `yield`s the statement you are passing to the `for ` clause b) nesting syntax is somewhat different, but you can find good reads about it, for instance https://spapas.github.io/2016/04/27/python-nested-list-comprehensions/

Comment: @wiesion I read it gave me some understanding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first translation should be

```
li=[]
for item in iterable: 
    li.append( expression )
```

Your example `[s+z for s in iterable_1 for z in iterable_2]` is translated as

```
li=[]
for s in iterable_1:
    for z in iterable_2:
        li.append(s+z)
```

Congrats, you have discovered ... *Monads!* which are essentially what you've described, *generalized* *nested* loops.

Nested loops just produce a plain stream of results. Nested *lists*, when *flattened*, also turn into a plain stream of elements. That's the similarity. A *lazy* `append` is pretty much like `yield`.

Each monad type is defined by how it implements *its version* of the `flatMap` function, which is a map followed by the flattening of the resulting nested structure, *splicing* the new values into the containing structure *in place*. The flattening of the nested structure at each nesting level allows for an *arbitrary* depth of nesting to be flattened:

```
M[ M[a]]  ==>  M[a]

M[ M[ M[a]]]  ==>   # flatten the two outer layers first:
                       M[ M[ M[a]]]
                       M[    M[a] ]  ==>  M[a]
               OR:
               ==>   # flatten the two inner layers first:
                       M[ M[ M[a]]]
                       M[ M[   a ]]  ==>  M[a]
```

See the difference? There isn't any! Any type that does the above, is a "monad". Like with lists,

```
    [ [ [a, b], [c] ], [], [ [], [d, e, f] ] ]
    [   [a, b], [c]  ,       [], [d, e, f]   ]
    [    a, b ,  c   ,            d, e, f    ]

    # or,
    [ [ [a, b], [c] ], [], [ [], [d, e, f] ] ]
    [ [  a, b ,  c  ], [], [      d, e, f  ] ]
    [    a, b ,  c   ,            d, e, f    ]
```

There really is no difference when we're focusing on the actual values *inside*, at the deepest level, while ignoring the containing "shell" structure. At this stage there's no point to all the "ornamental" noise anymore. It made a difference on how we got there, to that deepest level; but while there, it's played its role, and is no more.

<sub>Still the outer layer remains, enclosing the values in one particular type of container/producer/etc value, maintaining the encapsulation of the inner value(s) by the representative, wrapping type of value. All the "flattening" is done "on the inside", "under wraps". It is well defined when the flattening can be done in any order, leading to the same final result, so the order can be left unspecified. Like with multiplication, `3*4*2 = (3*4)*2 = 3*(4*2)`. With plain values like the numbers this is known as Monoid in maths, but with the higher-order, encapsulating values like list it is known as Monad (which *could* be referred to as higher-order monoids, but isn't, as far as I know).</sub>

So it is with loops as well, which can be nested to an arbitrary depth -- two, three, whatever, it doesn't matter. The whole structure is still producing its results one by one, and these are the results which the innermost loop is producing, one by one.

*That* is the under the hood reason why we can use nested *`for`* loops in list comprehensions. Or, saying the same thing in a fancy way, it is because list comprehensions are just like monadic chains of operations (and can be translated as such).

---

The *fixed* nested loops, i.e. such that are all known in advance (as shown above with the lists example),  correspond to so called Applicative (a.k.a. Monoidal) Functors. A side note, for lists specifically there are two distinct ways of combining two nested lists into one -- one way is combining them *sequentially*, leading to a "cross-product"-like combination, and the other way is *in parallel*, leading to a zipping-like combination, like the dot-product in maths (sans the final summation).

Non-nested "loops" (i.e. yielding producers) with *modifiable* yielded values are just plain Functors.

The crucial distinction of Monads is the ability to calculate the nested loops from *values* yielded by the loops above it. Or in your case,

```
li=[]
for s in iterable_1:
    for z in foo(s):      # for some appropriate foo()
        li.append(s+z)
```

or the equivalent `[s+z for s in iterable_1 for z in foo(s)]`.

This amounts to an Interpreter Pattern, in general terms.